# Git: Change default behavior of `git switch` form `--guess` to `--no-guess`

Tags: git

Is there any way to change default behavior of `git switch` from `--guess` to `--no-guess`? I checked man page of `git-switch(1)` and `git-config(1)` but couldn't find suitable configuration variable.

Answer (score 3):

According to the release note of Git 2.30, new configuration variable `checkout.guess` is added. So if you use 2.30 or later you can change default behavior of `git switch` to `--no-guess` with following command.

```
git config --global checkout.guess false
```

Comment: Hey, good one, thank you yasu (release notes for 2.30 [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.30.0.txt))

Answer (score 1):

I get that a config option would have been the "clean" solution, but the custom solution might just be to have an alias for that :

```
git config --global alias.sw 'switch --no-guess'

# then just
git sw <your-branch>
```